# linux systemd intercept shutdown if service is active

Tags: linux, systemd, shutdown

I've created a little update/upgrade program for my arch-based linux.
Instead of using a cronjob I'm using systemd and created following files:

in `/etc/systemd/system`: uupgrades.target & uupgrades.timer

```
[Unit]
Description=UU Upgrades Timer Target
StopWhenUnneeded=yes


[Unit]
Description=UU Upgrades Timer

[Timer]
OnBootSec=8min
OnUnitActiveSec=7h
Unit=uupgrades.target

[Install]
WantedBy=basic.target
```

in `/etc/systemd/system/uupgrades.target.wants` I've the `uupgrades.service` file

```
[Unit]
Description=UU Update Program

[Service]
Nice=19
IOSchedulingClass=2
IOSchedulingPriority=7
ExecStart=/usr/bin/uupgrades
```

and in `/etc/systemd/system/basic.target.wants` a symlink to `uupgrades.timer`

What I want to, is just that shutdown, reboot, suspend, hibernate, ... is delayed until uupgrades is not active anymore, when it is active.

How can I achieve this? A GUI/DE still running is not required.

Comment: Your question is answered in detail in the manual pages... take an inhibitor lock in the executable you are starting.. in this case /usr/bin/uupgrades.. Read the [Inhibitor Locks](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/inhibit/) documentation or [systemd-inhibit(1)](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-inhibit.html)

Answer (score 0):

For the suspend/hibernate/etc. stuff just obtain a logind inhibit. That logind inhibit shoul work for most shutdowns, but you can get around it in some situations I think.